# jQuery slider snippet, convert to plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I found this great little jquery image slider snippet:

```
var x = 2;
// function to switch the images.
function slideSwitch() {
          var m = 5;
           x += 1;
          if (x > m) {
            x = 1
            }

   $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(n)").animate({opacity:0});
   $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").animate({opacity:1});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

and have been trying to convert it to a plugin so to be able to use it multiple times but I'm not having any luck ...any help please.

***My attempt at plugin:*** (not working)

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.slidr = function (opts) {
    var def = {
      imgs : 4,
      sid  : 'slidr'
    },
    opts = $.extend({}, def, opts);

    var nxt = 2;

    this.each(function () {

var nxt += 1;

if (nxt > opts.imgs) {
     nxt = 1;
}

$('.'+ opts.sid + ' ul li:nth-child(n)').animate({opacity:0});
$('.'+ opts.sid + '  ul li:nth-child(' + (nxt) + ')').animate({opacity:1});

    });
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval( $('#content').slidr(), 2000);

});
```

Original snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7nX 
plugin attempt not working: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7nX/1

Comment: A JSFiddle example would be helpful here.

Comment: This `setInterval( $('#content').slidr(), 2000)` won't work. You need an anonymous function there `setInterval( function() { $('#content').slidr() }, 2000)`

Comment: @Will Demaine: Original snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7nX/  ...plugin attempt not working: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7nX/1/

Comment: @RoKo: Thanks but the original snippet works fine, I just want to turn it into a plugin for better mutliple use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would be re-inventing the wheel:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ 
This plugin does exactly what you need!

I also tweaked your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8T7nX/4/

You were overwriting your nxt var when you just wanted to add one to it (removed var from in front of it)

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.slidr = function (opts) {
    var def = {
      imgs : 4,
      sid  : 'slide'
    },
    opts = $.extend({}, def, opts);

    var nxt = 2;

    this.each(function () {

  nxt += 1;

if (nxt > opts.imgs) {
     nxt = 1;
}

$('.'+ opts.sid + ' ul li:nth-child(n)').animate({opacity:0});
$('.'+ opts.sid + '  ul li:nth-child(' + (nxt) + ')').animate({opacity:1});

    });
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval( function() { $('#content').slidr() }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: That does not mean that no one can build something for fun/learn

Comment: Reinventing ...maybe, but like Roko said "does not mean that no one can build something for fun/learn" which I am doing, I created an accordian plugin from a snippet I found a while ago and thought I'd do the same with this, also thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in where you went wrong with your original code then take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Willyham/JmgFV/

Though I would recommend reusing a much more comprehensive solution as the structure of this code leaves much to be desired.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.slidr = function(opts) {
        var def = {
            imgs: 4,
            timeout: 2000
        },
            opts = $.extend({}, def, opts);

        var nxt = 2;
        var el = $(this);

        function animate() {
            if (nxt > opts.imgs) nxt = 1;
            $('ul li:nth-child(n)', el).animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('ul li:nth-child(' + (nxt) + ')', el).animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            nxt++;
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            setInterval(animate, opts.timeout);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#n1').slidr();
    $('#n2').slidr({
        timeout: 5000
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for incorporating the setInterval

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's the fuzz about that script. It seems like you could be doing it simpler. This way you don't need to tell the plugin how many images you have.

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.slider = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
      var $li = $(this).find('li'),
          i = 1,
          slide
      $li.hide().first().show()
      slide = function(){
        $li.hide()
        if (i < $li.length) {
          $li.eq(i).fadeIn()
          i++
        } else {
          $li.first().fadeIn()
          i = 1
        }
      }
      setInterval(slide, 1000)
    })
  }
}(jQuery))
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8T7nX/5/

Comment: Always pay attention on your punctuation, specially when you write plugins.

Comment: No, you did not get the point. e.g. now if I try to minify your code you plugin will not work. Try it your self.

Comment: Try with uglifyjs. http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs or http://jscompress.com/. Works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8T7nX/9/